# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal not always functionning

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add some role management functionnalities in my WinForm application. By now, I added users, roles and rights in my database. User logs in with a specific form and the application retrieves its role through a service. 
Now I would like to set the Thread Principal to be able to use the role information anywhere.

```
private bool Login(string trigram, string password)
{
    using (var service = GetService())
    {
        //Permission.DummySet();
        _currentUser = service.Login(trigram, password);

        if (_currentUser != null)
        {
            Permission.DummySet();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("User unknown or incorrect password");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The Permission class :

```
public static class Permission
{
    private static bool _isSet = false;

    public static void DummySet()
    {
        if (!_isSet)
        {
            GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(
                new GenericIdentity("Serge Karamazov"),
                null);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(principal);
            _isSet = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The Login method works fine except that when I log in, the call to Permission.DummySet() does nothing. No error, no exception, but the principal of the thread is not set .
What is strange is when I uncomment the line just before the call to service.Login(trigram, password), the principal is now correctly set.

Obviously, the call to my service is the problem, but I cannot find why. The service is a business service in which I inject an instance of my datalayer using ninject. Maybe it has something to do with my problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in `DummySet` and traced it through, line by line?

Comment: Yes. The behavior of the method is the same in both cases (except it doesn't actually set the principal if the call is made after service.Login)